# Angular $compile directive not updating DOM object

Tags: javascript, angularjs, d3.js, angularjs-directive

I'm attempting to integrate AngularJS and D3 in an application which allows you to draw, drag, and resize shapes. I'm attempting to bind the attributes using angular to avoid having to manually update the DOM, but it isn't working.

I have the following code to create a rectangle. Basically, I create an SVG `group` object with a transform attribute that should be bound to scope variables. I then append a `rect` to that group:

```
var drawSquare = function () {
    console.log("DrawSquare");
    var id = uuid.v4();
    scope.objects[id] = { x: 0, y: 0, w: 40, h: 40 };
    var parent = d3.select(document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "g"))
        .attr("id", id)
        .attr("transform", "translate({{objects['" + id + "'].x}}, {{objects['" + id + "'].y}})");

    var element = parent.data([scope.objects[id]])
        .append("rect")
        .call(drag)
        .call(click);

    setSquareAttrs(element, id);
    //.attr(defaultSquare);
    console.log("parent", parent.node());
    $compile(parent.node())(scope);
    console.log("parent", parent.node());

    container.node().appendChild(parent.node());
};
```

I create the SVG `group` element, compile it with Angular, and then append it to the DOM. My drag handler updates the Angular object in `scope` to which the DOM object should be bound.

My drag handler is as follows:

```
// Main drag function.
var drag = d3.behavior.drag()
    .on("drag", function (d) {
        console.log("dragmove!", d3.event.x, d3.event.y);
        var id = d3.select(this.parentNode).attr("id");
        console.log("id", id);
        console.log("scopeobjects", scope.objects[id]);
        scope.objects[id].x = d3.event.x;
        scope.objects[id].y = d3.event.y;
    });
```

When I log my scope object in the console, I can see that it's being updated. However, the `transform` attribute on my `group` element is stuck at 0, 0. Does anyone see anything glaringly wrong? Has anyone run into a situation like this before where Angular interpolation bindings seem not to update?

Thank you.

Comment: are u facing problem in drag function it is better if you share plunker or fiddle demo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My dev team helped me find the answer to this. In order for bindings to update, it's necessary to either call `$scope.$apply` or `$scope.$digest`. This notifies Angular that something has changed and Angular will update all of its interpolated bindings. Change tracking apparently does not happen automatically in Angular directives.

The new code looked like this:

```
// Main drag function.
var drag = d3.behavior.drag()
    .on("drag", function (d) {
        console.log("dragmove!", d3.event.x, d3.event.y);
        var id = d3.select(this.parentNode).attr("id");
        console.log("id", id);
        console.log("scopeobjects", scope.objects[id]);
        scope.$apply(function () { // This wraps the changes.
            scope.objects[id].x = d3.event.x;
            scope.objects[id].y = d3.event.y;
        }
    });
```

The `translate` attribute now updates correctly.